# Unable to get a clickable link in angularjs ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, cursor

I am new to angular `(router ui-sref in angularjs)` and I am following a tutorial. But after code execution I am not able to get the clickable link. Instead of a clickable cursor, an edit cursor(|) is shown. Following is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
      <title>Insert title here</title>
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <!-- Optional theme -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
      <!-- SideBar Style Sheet -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/SideBar.css">
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
      <!-- SideBar Transition JS -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/sidebarAni.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min

" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


      
   </head>
   <body ng-app="myApp" >
  
  <a ui-sref="applyLeave">Apply Leave</a>
  <a href="#">Leave Balance1</a>
  <a href="#">Other Option</a>
  <a href="#">Other Option</a>
</div>
      <div  id="main">
         <ui-view></ui-view>
      </div>
  <script >
var v=angular.module("myApp",["ui.router"]);
v.config(function($stateProvider){
 $stateProvider
 .state("applyLeave",{
  url:"/applyLeave",
  templateUrl:"try.html",
  controller:"leaveController",
  controllerAs:"leaveController"
 })
 .controller("leaveController",function($scope)
   {
  
   })
});
</script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this. you have a mistake in closing `});` so this the controller puted on config body.

```
 var v=angular.module("myApp",["ui.router"]);
 v.config(function($stateProvider){
 $stateProvider
 .state("applyLeave",{
    url:"/applyLeave",
    templateUrl:"",
    controller:"leaveController",
    controllerAs:"leaveController"
 })
}); 

v.controller("leaveController",function($scope){

});
```

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/RIWsXdS0NvrPJmpMmJu8?p=preview)